# Java dynamically load plugin

Tags: java, plugins, runtime, classpath

I want to make an application that can dynamically load plug-ins but I've not found any literature on Internet.

The difficult thing is: I don't know the name in advance.

For example I've a **Plugin** interface:

```
public interface Plugin {
    public static Plugin newPlugin();
    public void executePlugin(String args[]);
}
```

So that every Class implementing **Plugin** in the jar file are instantiated in a list:

```
Method method = classToLoad.getMethod ("newPlugin");
mylist.add(method.invoke(null);
```

1. First problem is, I cannot have a **static** method in an interface.
2. Second problem is, I don't know how to find all classes that implement an interface

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is having a config file specifying which plugins to load a suitable solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi Mac, in my case I would like to avoid having a configuration file, just if a jar is present in a folder try to load it. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So it seems like you want to dynamically discover Classes that implement a specific interface (e.g., `Plugin`) at runtime. You have basically two choices for this:

1. Use a component framework like osgi
2. Use Java's internal discovery process (`ServiceLoader`)

Since there are many good tutorials on osgi (also small ones), I will not detail that here. To use Java's internal discovery process, you need to do the following:

- Bundle all "new" classes that you wish to discover into a jar file
- Create a new file **inside** the jar file: `META-INF/services/package.Plugin` You must use the full package qualifier here
- This file is a simple text file and contains the fully qualified name of each class implementing `Plugin` in that jar-file
- Place that jar file into the classpath of your (potentially already running) application
- Discover the services:

Service discovery is done like this:

```
ServiceLoader<Plugin> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class)
for (Plugin p : loader) {
    // do something with the plugin
}
```

There are more details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

As for static methods in interfaces: not possible. The semantics of that would also be somewhat weird as static methods are accessible without an instance of a class, and interfaces just define the methods, without any functionality. Thus, static would allow to call `Interface.doSomething()` whereas the interface does not define any functionality, this leads just to confusion.

edit:

added description what should be in the meta-file

Comment: I don't think anybody said welcome to you SirRichie, but you are very welcome to this community. Voted up all four of your answers :)

Comment: Normally you just indent the first line with 4 spaces, after you skipped a line. Then after another empty line you start at position 0 for the rest of your normal text. You can surround code with `` characters for inline code.

Comment: Yeah... I did that. Now I found out that this does not work, if the code immediately follows a list item. So I put some filler text there and it works like a charm now.

Comment: While an interface can't have a static method, an abstract class can, and abstract classes work with SPI jars just as interfaces do.  The (pleasantly short) SPI jar specification is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service_Provider).

Comment: Actual URL of the ServiceLoader class is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html - the one in the text refers to the whole Java API ;)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first problem, not being able to have static methods in the interface, my suggestion is to simply use the interface has a marker and instantiate it.

You're plugin interface can simply be:

```
public interface Plugin {
  public void executePlugin(String args[]);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
if (someClass instanceOf Plugin) {
  mylist.add(someClass.newInstance());
}
```

This leads to the second question, how will you get the `someClass` reference.
**There is no standard way** to find all classes implementing a given interface **in your classpath**, although, an approach you can do is scan the jars in your classpath, if a given file ends with `.class` determine it's full qualified name through it's path inside the jar and use `Class.forName()` method to materialize the Class.

In pseudo code something like this:

```
for each jar in your classpath {
  for each file in JarFile {
    if (file ends with .class) {
       materialize class using Class.forName
     } 
  }
}
```

With the `Class` instance you can check if it's implementing your `Plugin` interface.

Also keep in mind that if you need to add any context to your plugins you can create a constructor in every plugin that receives your context object, instead of having the default constructor. In such case instead of using `newInstance()` you would have to get the constructor with arguments you wanted via reflection.